# What is the correct syntax for working with Dates in DB2?

Tags: date, db2

I am writing a SQL statement that may be used against a number of database types.
I have never worked with DB2 before, and am unsure of the syntax for working with dates.
The dates are stored as a date type.
Here is a snippet of the statement against a SQL Server database:
SELECT * from tbl1 where YEAR(Start_Time) = YEAR(GetDate() -365)

I thinking that the equivalent in DB2 would be:
SELECT * from tbl1 where YEAR(Start_Time) = YEAR(current_date -365 days)

Unfortunately, I don't have a DB2 environment at my home office (thanks to COVID-19)

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1

Comment: @data_henrik The Db2 fiddle seems offline.

Comment: DB2 LUW dev licenses exist, and there are official docker images, I believe.  Outside of that, as per usual, `SOME_FUNCTION(column)` is going to ignore indices in essentially any RDBMS - doing a regular range query (with an exclusive upper bound!) is preferred: `WHERE start_time >= :this_year_january_first - 1 YEAR AND start_time < :this_year_january_first`.  Remember that years are not all 365 days - are you sure you want days instead of years?

Answer (score 1):

[Datetime operations and durations](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023457.html)

```
SELECT Start_Time
FROM
(
VALUES 
  CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 365 DAYS - 1 HOUR - 1 MINUTE - 1 SECOND - 1 MICROSECOND
, CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 365 DAYS
) tbl1 (Start_Time) 
WHERE YEAR(Start_Time) = YEAR(CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 365 DAYS);
```

The result is:

```
|START_TIME                |
|--------------------------|
|2019-04-08-15.17.17.613999|
|2019-04-08-16.18.18.614000|
```

Comment: leap years on 31/12 is interesting :-) Subtracting 1 year is an alternative: `YEAR(CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 1 YEAR)`